Find the taylor expansion of composite functions $g(f(x))$ centered around $0$ when $f(0)$ is not $0$.
I have to find the taylor expansion (approximation?) to the 4th order of this composite functions
$$f(x) = \log(\cos(x))$$
I already know we can plug the taylor expansion of cos(x) in the function, so that gives us
$$f(x) = \log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{x^4}{24} + x^4*\mathcal{O}(x)\right)$$
Then I know that I can write $X= 1-\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{x^4}{24} + x^4*\mathcal{O}(x)$, and then write $f(x) = \log(1+(X-1))$ to finally have
$$f(x) = \log(1+y)$$
where $y=X-1$.
Then I could use the taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$.
The problem is, during lesson, my professor told us that to find the taylor expansion when we have composite functions in the form $g(f(x))$, we have to find the expansion of $f(x)$ centered around $0$, and then plot it in the expansion of $g(x)$ centered around $\mathbf{f(0)}$. But here, $\cos(0)=1$, so we would need to plug the expansion of $\cos(x)$ in the taylor expansion of $\log(x)$ centered around $1$.
So why can we use the expansion $\log(1+x)$ if it's an expansion that is centered around $0$?

See the $\color{red}{first\ example}$ in Fa$\rm\grave{a}$ di Bruno’sFormula.

Were you told to do this problem specifically by composition of functions? Because in this case it is much easier to differentiate $\log\cos x$ four times and evaluate them at $0$. But for your question, it is $X = \cos x$, not $y$. If you want to still consider the inside function to be $\cos x$, then the outside function is $\log x$, not $\log(1+x)$, and the taylor expansion of $\log x$ about $1$ is the same as the taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ about $0$.

Is the taylor expansion of $log(x)$ about $1$ the same as the expansion of $log(x+1)$ about $0$ because we "shifted" the function to the left ? If that's it, you answered my question. And yes, I had to do the problem with composition of functions.

By the chain rule, when $x\to x_0$ we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(g(x))
&=f(g(x_0))+\\
&+f'(g(x_0))\,g'(x_0)\,(x-x_0)+\\
&+\frac{1}{2}\left(f''(g(x_0))\,g'(x_0)^2+f'(g(x_0))\,g''(x_0)\right)(x-x_0)^2+\\
&+\dots+\\
&+o((x-x_0)^n).
\end{aligned}
$$
So, if you want to try, you can have fun with direct calculation.
On the other hand, if for $x\to 0$ we know that:
$$
\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4),
\qquad
\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+o(x^4)
$$
then for $x\to 0$ it follows that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log(\cos(x))
&=\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\right)\\
&=\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\right)-\frac{\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\right)^2}{2}+\dots\\
&=-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{12}+o(x^4)
\end{aligned}
$$
and this way we avoid doing a ton of calculations.

So the final anwer $-\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{12} + \omicron (x^4)$ is a Taylor expansion centered around 1 ? If it is, I can't see why.

I think what is bugging me is that my professor said we should find the expansion $log(cos(x))$ centered around $cos(0)=1$, and in this step: $log(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\omicron(x^4)) = (-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\omicron(x^4)) - ...$ we use the $log(1+x)$ expansion which is centered around 0.
